# Изменение структуры большой базы mySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, таблицы

У вас есть база размером свыше 100гб и более 8млн строк.
Необходимо добавить 3 новых поля, переименовать одно поле, а также добавить два индекса.
Как это лучше делать?

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос, думаю поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159029/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5/1159124#1159124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы убедиться, что база остаётся доступна - добавьте в команду ALTER параметр LOCK:

```
ALTER TABLE big
    ADD field1 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    ADD field2 DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    ADD field3 TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    ALGORITHM=INPLACE,
    LOCK=NONE;
```

Если на середине процесса выдаст ошибку - возможно, придётся увеличить значение параметра `innodb_online_alter_log_max_size` у MySQL и повторить попытку.